# How to reset a TabPage's header title?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with five Tabs and `DrawMode` set to `OwnerDrawFixed`. What I actually try to do is to change the font color of the last tab header from black to blue. The following code that handles the `DrawItem`-Event works fine and shows the also following tabs:

Code:

```
private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Index == 4)
            {                
                e.Graphics.DrawString("Notifications", new Font(tabControl.Font, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(SystemColors.HotTrack), new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl.TabPages[e.Index].Text, tabControl.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(e.Bounds.X + 5, e.Bounds.Y + 3));
            }
        }
```

GUI:

[image]

As soon as I click on one of the tabs, the header font itself changes a bit, it becomes a bit "thicker". I don't really know how to describe it, so here's a picture:

[image]

What I did here was clicking the first three tabs. I already know that it's because of the `DrawItem`-Event that paints over the already existing font.

So my question now is: Can I "reset" the tab header's font inside the handler so the font isn't painted over every time and becomes thicker when the event is fired?

I already tried using `e.Graphics.Clear()` (because I thought it would just "clear" the header), however this doesn't show the header title afterwards when I draw it using `e.Graphics.DrawString()`.

Does anyone have an idea how to bypass this "process of overpainting"?

EDIT:

I figured out that the behavior only occurs when you set the `TabControl`'s property `Appearance` to `Buttons`, as I did. The other values do not make the behavior occur.

So is there any possibility to bypass this when the `Appearance` property is set to `Buttons`?

Comment: I made this and am not getting the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: I figured out that the behavior only occurs when you set the `TabControl`'s property `Appearance` to `Buttons`, as I did. The other values do not make the behavior occur. Does it happen to you too?

Comment: try putting e.DrawBackground() in before your statement so it paints the underlying part - however.. for me this didnt paint it in the colour expected..

Comment: Setting `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;` seems to help.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks @TaW!

Comment: Also highly recommended: Using TextRenderer.DrawText instead of Graphics.DrawString !! It will work even without the rendering hint..